# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to host my rails website on Amazon Elestic Beanstalk. I followed this guide : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html.

Now, I have this error : Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

> Error message:
>
> ```
> Could not find rake-10.0.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) Exception class:
>
> PhusionPassenger::UnknownError Application root:
>
> /var/app/current
> ```
>
> 0  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   90  in `block in materialize'
>
> 1  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   83  in `map!'
>
> 2  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   83  in `materialize'
>
> 3  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb     113     in `specs'
>
> 4  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb     158     in `specs_for'
>
> 5  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb     147     in `requested_specs'
>
> 6  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb    23  in `requested_specs'
>
> 7  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    11  in `setup'
>
> 8  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb    116     in `setup'
>
> 9  /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    326     in `prepare_app_process'
>
> 10     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb     156     in `block in initialize_server'
>
> 11     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    563     in `report_app_init_status'
>
> 12     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb     154     in `initialize_server'
>
> 13     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  204     in `start_synchronously'
>
> 14     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  180     in `start'
>
> 15     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb     129     in `start'
>
> 16     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager_orig.rb   253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
>
> 17     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132     in `lookup_or_add'
>
> 18     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager_orig.rb   246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'
>
> 19     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `block in synchronize'
>
> 20         prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
>
> 21     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
>
> 22     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager_orig.rb   244     in `spawn_rack_application'
>
> 23     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager_orig.rb   137     in `spawn_application'
>
> 24     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    16  in `spawn_application_with_env'
>
> 25     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager_orig.rb   275     in `handle_spawn_application'
>
> 26     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357     in `server_main_loop'
>
> 27     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206     in `start_synchronously'
>
> 28     /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server     99  in `'

Nothing one the trace in on my source code. I didn't found anything on the Internet. You can find the source code of the application here : https://github.com/GCorbel/comment-my-projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experiencing that, and found out that this isn't related with rake itself. That's happening probably because one of your gems isn't getting installed. In my case, it was `pg` that wasn't getting installed since it needs the pg_config executable.

So, in my case, to fix that, I added the following sections to `.ebextensions/default.config`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql-devel: []

# Run rake tasks before an application deployment
container_commands:
  01bundler-pg:
    command: bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config
```

Even if you don't use `pg`, check if any of your gems needs development headers or executable files installed.

Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=400055